# Put correct labels on y-axis with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, yaxis

I have an OHLC candlestick graph and i want put the correct labels on y-axis but i cant, i want to put the close price in y-axis. This is my code and data.

the graph looks like this : https://i.imgsafe.org/2354d30039.jpg

> datos_tratados.csv
>
> datetime, open, high, low, close
>
> ```
> 201611010000,1.096100,1.096140,1.096100,1.096130
> 201611010001,1.096130,1.096200,1.096130,1.096160
> 201611010002,1.096150,1.096210,1.096140,1.096150
> 201611010003,1.096140,1.096170,1.096130,1.096140
> 201611010004,1.096150,1.096220,1.096150,1.096220
> 201611010005,1.096220,1.096320,1.096220,1.096300
> 201611010006,1.096300,1.096340,1.096300,1.096340
> 201611010007,1.096350,1.096360,1.096320,1.096340
> 201611010008,1.096360,1.096370,1.096350,1.096370
> 201611010009,1.096370,1.096410,1.096340,1.096360
> 201611010010,1.096360,1.096380,1.096360,1.096360
> 201611010011,1.096370,1.096370,1.096370,1.096370
> 201611010012,1.096370,1.096370,1.096300,1.096320
> 201611010013,1.096320,1.096390,1.096300,1.096380
> 201611010014,1.096380,1.096410,1.096360,1.096380
> 201611010015,1.096370,1.096370,1.096350,1.096360
> 201611010016,1.096350,1.096350,1.096320,1.096320
> 201611010017,1.096290,1.096300,1.096290,1.096300
> 201611010018,1.096320,1.096420,1.096320,1.096420
> 201611010019,1.096440,1.096440,1.096350,1.096370
> 201611010020,1.096360,1.096530,1.096340,1.096530
> 201611010021,1.096500,1.096520,1.096480,1.096520
> 201611010022,1.096510,1.096520,1.096480,1.096510
> 201611010023,1.096520,1.096530,1.096490,1.096520
> 201611010024,1.096520,1.096610,1.096520,1.096560
> 201611010025,1.096570,1.096790,1.096570,1.096790
> 201611010026,1.096770,1.096830,1.096660,1.096820
> 201611010027,1.096810,1.096850,1.096800,1.096810
> 201611010028,1.096790,1.096790,1.096680,1.096690
> 201611010029,1.096690,1.096700,1.096680,1.096700
> ```

the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.finance import date2num
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as md
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

# Generar numpy.array con los 4 datos, convirtiendo la fecha en flotante para graficar
convertir = lambda x: date2num(datetime.strptime(x.decode("utf-8"), '%Y%m%d%H%M'))
fecha, apertura, alto, bajo, cierre = np.loadtxt('datos_tratados.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True,
                                                 converters={0: convertir})


style.use('dark_background')
plt.rc('font', size=10)
figura, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.title('EURUSD', size=15)
plt.grid(False)

ohlc = []
for i in range(len(fecha)):
    agregar = fecha[i], apertura[i], alto[i], bajo[i], cierre[i]
    ohlc.append(agregar)

# Generar el gráfico ohlc y configuraciones básicas del eje x
#plt.plot(fecha, cierre)
candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc, width=0.0004, colorup='lime', colordown='red')
xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%d %b %H:%M')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(90)

# plt.xticks(fecha)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(25))
plt.xlim(min(fecha) - 0.001, max(fecha) + 0.0017)
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.01, bottom=0.20, right=0.94, top=0.90, wspace=0.2, hspace=0)
plt.show()
```

how can I do it?

Comment: Following advice of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, just put `ax.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)` in after the statement where you indicate that you want y-axis ticks on the right (if you haven't already done something).

Comment: Bill, Thanks for the solution.

Comment: You're most welcome.